# Handling Headers and Subheaders with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with headers and subheaders, I can pull the names of these easily enough, but am struggling to access specific headers or subs.

Essentially I'm needing to use header and subheaders as keys and then check that all data in those columns are in the correct order.

Currently I have a list of tuples pulling from the date headers/subheaders in the spreadsheet listed in the chronological order in which they should occur.

Headers/Subs in below format:

```
                      Header1                     Header2      Header3
participant_number   Subheader1-1 Subheader1-2   Subheader2-1  (no subheader)
```

I think the below section is working:

```
date_columns= [(list of tuples,'')]
for column_name, column_labels in date_columns.items():
    header_label = column_labels[0]
    subheader_label = column_labels[1]

    column_index = None
    for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns):
        if col[0] == header_label or col[1] == subheader_label:
            column_index = idx
            break

    if column_index is not None:
        df[column_name] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, column_index], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

But this section is not:

```
participant_errors = {}

for current_column, next_column in zip(date_columns, date_columns[1:]):
    mask = ~(df[current_column].apply(pd.isna) | df[next_column].apply(pd.isna) | (df[current_column] <= df[next_column]))

    errors = df.loc[mask, [('key', '')] + (current_column[0], current_column[1]) + (next_column[0], next_column[1])]

    for row in errors.itertuples():
        participant_number = row[('key', '')]
        current_value = getattr(row, current_column[0])[row.Index]
        next_value = getattr(row, next_column[0])[row.Index]

        if participant_number not in participant_errors:
            participant_errors[participant_number] = {current_column[0]: f"check data: {current_column[0]} ({current_value},) should occur before {next_column[0]} ({next_value})"}
        else:
            participant_errors[participant_number][current_column[0]] = f"check data: {current_column[0]} ({current_value},) should occur before {next_column[0]} ({next_value})"

print(participant_errors)
```

Comment: You keep mentioning Excel, but this is a pandas DataFrame.  Excel is irrelevant. I think you need to frame the problem in pandas terms to get reasonable help.  Can you show the data causing trouble?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks, have updated, hope that's clearer